# What is the best way to properly add a custom command in the generated Makefile by using CMake?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, cmake-custom-command

I would like to use a **CMakeLists.txt** file to generate a Makefile with specific custom commands to use them in a terminal like this :

`$> make command1
...
$> make command2
...`

I have looked for [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/add_custom_command.html) but I don't want to generate an output file when I'm running a command. I also heard about CMake functions but I'm not sure we can use them in a terminal, unless I missed something.

So, what is the best way to properly add a custom command in the generated Makefile by using CMake ?

Comment: [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) adds a target with no output, so it will always be built.

Comment: I knew this option too but I would like have a command who it can be used without the building step